# Magento NGINX allow IP/deny all for downloader folder

Tags: magento-1.9, nginx

I'm having a problem allowing my IP address access to the downloader folder when using nginx to deny all other IP's. Any ideas where I'm going wrong with the below? I've tried with my IPv4 and IPv6 address, neither works and results in a 403 forbidden.
(Domain and IP I've replaced for security)

```
   server {
    listen   80 default;

    root /var/www/mywebsiteaddress.co.uk/httpdocs;
    server_name mywebsiteaddress.co.uk;

    location / {
        index index.html index.php;
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ @handler;
    }

    ## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
    location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
    location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
    location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
    location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
    location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }
    location ^~ /downloader/     { allow 123.456.789.0; deny all; }


    location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
        auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
        auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
        autoindex            on;
    }

    location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
        return 404;
    }

    location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
        rewrite / /index.php;
    }

    location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
        rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

        expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
        fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Comment: do you see your ip address in access log?

Answer (score 0):

I know this i an old post, but we block access to magmi like this:

```
   location ~* ^/(index.php/)?magmi {

     include includes/admin-ips;

     deny all;
```

With admin-ips being a text file with a list of ipaddress eg:

```
allow **.***.**.**/32;
```